# Symfony functional tests for wildcard subdomains

Tags: symfony, functional-testing

Do you know how to use wildcard subdomains (dynamic subdomains) in symfony functional tests?
Here is my code:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/');
$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

This fails obviously because the home page of the app is always: someusername.mydomain.com.
How can I specify the subdomain?

Comment: as far as I know, the tests are run on localhost (in the console). Therefore, in my opinion, set a (sub) domain makes no sense.

Comment: @Anton, thank you for your input. The app does not have a regular domain. Every user has their own subdomain. For unit tests it doesn't really matter, but for functional tests I need to find some way of accomplishing this. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: I would create a fake user account for the tests - this can also be a test. If it still doesn't work, it's probably an architecture problem. A user should be authenticated via an authenticator. The subdomain should only be a frontend thing (redirection or something else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After diving into symfony source code I found the solution:

```
$client = static::createClient([], ['HTTP_HOST' => 'someusername.mydomain.com']);
```